# Trouble with string-replacing in a subset of R columns

Tags: r

I've tried to read through the archives to find a solution but no luck.  I want to replace a string ("_" with " ") in a subset of columns in R:

```
January_2019= c(4, 5)

February_2019= c(1,2)

OtherVariable = c(3,5)

dateColumns <- c("January_2019",
                 "February_2019")

df <- data.frame(January_2019, February_2019, OtherVariable)

colnames(df[dateColumns]) <- gsub("_", " ", colnames(df[dateColumns]))
```

I cannot figure out why this is not working. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version of OP's code, we can use `match` to find the index of 'dateColumns' for subsetting.  Although the `gsub` code works for the whole columns, it is assumed that the question is about how to use `gsub` on a subset of columns

```
i1 <- match(dateColumns, names(df))
names(df)[i1] <- gsub("_", " ", names(df)[i1])
names(df)
#[1] "January 2019"  "February 2019" "OtherVariable"
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
        rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., '_', ' '), all_of(dateColumns))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is really this:

```
names(df) <- gsub("_", " ", names(df))
```

Result:

```
df
  January 2019 February 2019 OtherVariable
1            4             1             3
2            5             2             5
```

Comment: Why can't I use names(df) with a subset of columns, and have it work?  For example, what if I only want to replace the underscore in specific columns?